# Probability of number of equally spaced numbers

Tags: probability

If you have a uniform sample of size $\ell$ of integers taken from $[1,\dots,n]$ which is then sorted, how do you calculate the probability that there exists an equally spaced subsequence of length  $k$ (or at least $k$)?

As an example, if the sample is $\{1,5,10, 15,18,20\}$ so $\ell = 6$ and let us say that $n= 30$, then there is a subsequence of length $4$ which are equally spaced from each other.

Comment: Numbers are taken at most once?

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien No let us say sampling with replacement.

Comment: An exact formula is unlikely to exist. Would you be interested in asymptotics, and if so, which ones?

Comment: @Did Yes please. Asymptotics or large n approximations would be great or even some good bounds.  A typical case might be n >  50000 and l < 5000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an attempt. It seems that unless $\ell$ is a constant fraction of $n$ we expect to see only very short arithmetic progressions (APs). On the other hand, if $\ell > \epsilon n$ for some constant $\epsilon>0$, then there will be APs of logarithmic length.

Here is the proof:

Let us first count how many arithmetic progressions of length $t$ there are in the interval $[1,n]$.

Claim1: The number of arithmetic progressions of length $t$ in the interval $[1,n]$ is $\approx n^2/2t$

Proof:The number of $t$-APs with difference 1 is $n-t$. The number of $t$-APs with difference 2 is $n-2t$. And so on. Therefore, the number of APs in the interval $[1,n]$ is
$$
(n-t) + (n-2t) + (n-3t) + \dots + (n - \frac{n}{t}t) \approx n^2/2t.
$$

Let us fix a $t$-AP. We ask what is the probability that a random sample $S \subseteq [n]$ of size $|S| = \ell$ contains this AP.

Claim2: $(\frac{\ell-t}{n-t})^t \leq \Pr[\{1,\dots,t\} \in S] \leq (\frac{\ell}{n})^t$.

Proof: Suppose we choose $S$ without repetitions. Then $\Pr[\{1,\dots,t\} \subseteq S] = \frac{{n-t \choose \ell - t}}{{n \choose \ell}}$.

Therefore, the expected number of $t$-APs in a random $S$ is
$$
\frac{n^2}{2t} \cdot (\frac{\ell-t}{n-t})^t
\leq 
\mathbb{E}[\text{number of $t$-APs in $S$}]
\leq \frac{n^2}{2t} \cdot (\frac{\ell}{n})^t
$$
Therefore, if $t > \frac{2\log(n)}{\log(n) - \log(\ell)}$, then we don't expect to see $t$-APs in a random sample of length $\ell$.

On the other hand, if $\ell > n^{1-2/t}$ then we expect to see $t$-APs.